# How do i get particular value from rest API response array object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

In the below code I have the result which is fetching data from GET API

```
this.Authserviceservice.loginform(username).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        if (this.formgroup.value.username === result.username && this.formgroup.value.password ===
            result.password) {
            this.activatedRoute.navigate(['login']);
```

when the console logged of result in the browser I receive an array JSON object below

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 4, firstname: "Aduri", lastname: "Manasa", username: "aduri.manasa@gmail.com", password: "****"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

If I try to access the results, username is *undefined*.
How can I get username value from the above data?

Comment: it is an Array of Objects just like you said. So you have to access the array element that you want the username from: `result[0].username` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's assume we use i as an index

```
result[i].username
```

so it should work

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the backend? if you do try to modify it there since a login shouldn't return an array.
If you're just a consumer you can be a bit hacky an access the first element of the array if it exists

```
result = result.length> 0 : result[0] : null
```